# Finding the absolute min and max

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of f on the given interval.
$$f(x)=4-x^2;\;\; x\in [-3,1]$$

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange

Comment: You forgot to say please... (quote from Terminator 2)

Comment: Actually, you rather forgot to tell us what you have tried, what is your level of knowledge ...

Answer (score 2):

We have $$f(x) = 4-x^2$$

$(1)\;$ Find $f'(x)$

$(2)\;$ Set $f'(x) = 0$ and solve for $x = x_0$.

$(3)\;$ Evaluate $\;f(-3),\;f(1),\;f(x_0)$ to identify which is/are absolute maximum(s), which is absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Set the derivate zero to find the local extrema and consider the values
        f(-3) and f(1) to find the global extrema.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2\ge 0$ so that $4\ge 4-x^2$.

If we have $x\gt y\gt 0$ then $(4-x^2)-(4-y^2)=(x+y)(x-y)$ is the product of two positive numbers, so the function is increasing for $x\gt 0$.

If $y\lt x \lt 0$ then the difference is is the product of a negative factor and a positive one, so the function is decreasing as $x$ increases for $x\lt 0$.

This is sufficient to identify the possible maximum/minimum points without using calculus.